# Two textbox change at same time [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two textboxes one is `type='text'` and second is `type='hidden`'.I want to when something is typed in first textbox to set same value in the second automatically.

I tried something with `.change()`, but it was not good.

In short: I want same value on both textboxes at sometime [real time]

Do you have some idea how to do it?

Comment: along with `change` listen to `keyup`, `input`, `paste` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keyup` as below

```
 $("#txt1").on('keyup',function(){
   $("#txt2").val($(this).val())
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change event for `keyup` event,

```
$("#txt1").keyup(function()
{
 $("#txt2").val($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#txt1").keyup(function(){
   $("#txt2").val($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `keyup()` of JQuery. It is called when user releases a key on the keyboard.

```
$("#txtbox").keyup(function(){
   $("#hiddentextbox").val($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/):

```
$("#txt").on("keydown", function(){
   $("#hid").val($(this).val());
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmy5or4f/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the input event:

```
$('#txt1').on('input',function() {
    $('txt2').val( this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML code

`input type = "text" size = "40" id = "inputText">
<input type = "text" size = "40" id = "outputText" value = "" readonly>`

jQuery script

`$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#inputText').keyup(function(){
                $('#outputText').val($(this).val());
            });
        });`

Hope this would be helpful to you. Thank you for the useful question.

Answer (score 0):

use `.blur` as :-

```
$("#txt1").blur(function(){
   $("#txt2").val($(this).val())
});
```

OR

```
$("#txt1").keyup(function(){
  $("#txt2").val($(this).val())
});
```